# BigDecimal to values monetary

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have two float values:

```
float value1 = 1.9f;
float value2 = 20;
```

I want to multiply them and get an exact result, so I use `BigDecimal` and expect 38 as result:

```
BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal(value1).multiply(new BigDecimal(value2));

System.out.println(total); // 37.99999952316284179687500
```

When I do the same test with 10 and 1.9, I get 18.99999976158142089843750 instead of 19.

**Why do I lose precision?**

Comment: You want a round value or exact value

Comment: You should use `BigDecimal` from the start. When the value is inside `double` or `float`, it has already lost precision.

Comment: but it is small numbers and is coming from database, but are a table static with values little

Comment: should me i change value in database float for?

Comment: No need for that what you want is *10 * 1.9 = 18.99999976158142089843750 and not 19* right and what do you mean by *i make text using calcular windows,*

Comment: sorry typing error, mean i do test using calculator from windows ;)

Comment: So what value you want 19 or 18.99999976158142089843750 ..And why are you testing it against calculator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-) for the BigDecimal(double) constructor:

> The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One might assume that writing new BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a double (or, for that matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to 0.1, appearances notwithstanding.

And although your variables are floats, there is not ctor that takes floats, so they are cast as doubles. And like the docs say, if you used Strings for your values, you would get the exact result (38) you expect.

Answer (score 1):

The error is right at the start:

```
float value1 = 1.9f;
```

You may think that `value1` now contains exactly the value 1.9. But this is not the case. Floating point values are stored in binary. The important thing to remember is that some real values cannot be expressed by a finite sequence of digits, such as a `float`. 1.9 is such a number (just like in decimal the value 1.333... cannot be expressed by a finite sequence of digits).

So you should use `BigDecimal` from the start. Then the values can be exactly represented (because it is not stored in binary but in decimal) and the calculation results in the expected answer.

Comment: nice explanation too :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your value1 is a double as primitive type and want to output 2 decimal places and the value1 is 350. 4432567

```
 double roundTotal = Math.round(value1 * 100.0) / 100.0;
    or
    double roundTotal = (double) Math.round(value1 * 100) / 100;

Output:
  350.44


Note that the 2 digits precision.  Zeros indicate the wanted number of decimal to display.

Example #2
double roundTotal = (double) Math.round(value1 * 10000) / 10000;
Output:
  350.4432
```

Comment: but 10 * 1.9 should be 19 in this test output 18.99999976158142089843750

Comment: @Ricardo-- try this: double roundTotal = Math.round(total * 100.0) / 100.0;
    if you want two decimals places.

Comment: well i convert de values to string then i use string how paramters to BigDecimal now work, ty bro

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Math.floor(float f);
//or
Math.ceil(float f);
```

functions for the exact value. Or you can override these functions for BigDecimal class.